# Display RealmList as child of RealmList

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, realm

I have a requirement to display two related lists of Realm objects (Entrances and associated Gates) in the following layout:

> **ENTRANCE A  IN=130 OUT=80**
>   Gate 1      IN=23 OUT=12
>   Gate 2      IN=45 OUT=23
>   Gate 3      IN=62 OUT=45
>
> **ENTRANCE B  IN=6543 OUT=675**
>   Gate 1      IN=23 OUT=12
>   Gate 2      IN=45 OUT=23
>   Gate 3      IN=62 OUT=45
>   Gate 4      IN 1234 OUT=234

As you can see GATES are linked to ENTRANCES and there may be more gates in one entrance than the other.
I have created and populated the Realm objects but I don't know how to display the data. I have successfully used RealmRecyclerView to display single object lists but don't see how I can use this to display a list within a list.

Comment: Use an ExpendableListView. It's basically nested lists that you can collapse/expand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make an adapter for your RecyclerView that can show the elements from multiple RealmResults, which you treat as lists. You must calculate the number of groups and the number of elements within the groups total to define your `getItemCount()`, and determine for each position whether it's a group or element, and bind the right item for the given position.

Don't forget to include `RealmChangeListener` for the relevant tables, or the Realm instance itself.

Comment: So would I pass in the Entrances list to the adapter and from within the adapter query the realm to get the list of Gates for each Entrance? The Gates count is not necessarily the same for each Entrance. How would I configure the layout? I also need the Entrances and Gates to update as new data is received.

Comment: I've solved this problem before but never abstracted it, the key to the solution were `private Map<Integer, RealmResults<Channel>> groupPositionToChannelsMap = Collections.emptyMap();` and `private Map<Integer, Integer> groupPositionToRealmIndexMap = Collections.emptyMap();`

Comment: I've used this https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter and it seems to do the job. Thanks